# Collation abbreviation, not sure of meaning

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**UPDATE**:
Running this:

```
 ALTER DATABASE "STRINGSDB.MDF"
    COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AShere
```

Getting this error:

Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
Msg 5072, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'STRINGSDB.MDF' cannot be set to Latin1_General_CS_AS.

I only have SQL server Management Studio accessing the DB.

**ORIGINAL POST**:

My SQLEE indicates a Collation of...
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

I am having problems finding the meaning of the CP1, does anyone know what this means?

I also ran...

select * from ::fn_helpcollations()

and the 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
doesn't exist, also checked...
Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SQL Server Collation Name (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx):

> CP1 specifies code page 1252

Comment: @Oded, Do I need to include this when specifying a change to the Collation? Like SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS when changing to Case Insensitive?

Comment: @marc11h - If you change the collation, you should specify the same codepage, otherwise you risk the data getting corrupt.